# How to preserve spaces in the Visual Editor of WordPress?

Tags: formatting

My client is trying to be able to copy and paste formatting from a Word document into WordPress and have the spacing be preserved (he is copying/pasting a poem written by a 3rd party). The Visual Editor in WordPress is removing the spaces by default. How can I get the spacing to stay? I need to make sure my client is able to copy and paste his text from Word into the Visual Editor because he does not know code. I've tried the following, but it hasn't worked:

I've tried adding this to the functions:

```
function allow_nbsp_in_tinymce( $mceInit ) {
$mceInit['entities'] = '160,nbsp,38,amp,60,lt,62,gt';   
return $mceInit;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'allow_nbsp_in_tinymce' );
```

If there was something like this, but instead of removing the spaces, it preserved them, that would be good: https://wordpress.org/plugins/space-remover/#reviews

Any ideas?